# Phonegap - How to download files

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to export / download info to a file. In my browser it works fine, but as soon as I have it in my phonegap app, all it does is open the file as text with no way to save it and then no way to get back to the app.
Any suggestions? By the way, I am no js expert - more like a novice!

```
    function dbError(e) {
        console.log("SQL ERROR");
        console.dir(e);
    }

    function backup(table) {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    curatio.webdb.db.readTransaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select * from "+table, [], function(tx,results) {
            var data = convertResults(results);
            console.dir(data);
            def.resolve(data);
        });
    }, dbError);

    return def;
}

$(document).on("click", "#doBackupBtn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Begin backup process");

    $.when(
        backup("allergies")

    ).then(function(allergies, log) {
        console.log("All done");
        var data = {allergies:allergies}
        var serializedData = JSON.stringify((data), null, 4);
        console.log(serializedData);
        download("Export.csv", serializedData); 

        (function(console){

console.save = function(data, filename){

    if(!data) {
        console.error('Console.save: No data')
        return;
    }

    if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

    if(typeof data === "object"){
        data = JSON.stringify(data)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
        e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a    = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
 }
})(console)


    });

});


    function download(filename, content) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(content));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    pom.click();
    }

    //Generic utility
function convertResults(resultset) {
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0,len=resultset.rows.length;i<len;i++) {
        var row = resultset.rows.item(i);
        var result = {};
        for(var key in row) {
            result[key] = row[key];
        }
        results.push(result);
    }
    return results;
}


        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read it correct, you want to export (and import?) a database to a file.

I wrote some code to do that on my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/teusinkorg/5892402) on Github, which is also explained in my [blogpost](http://teusink.blogspot.nl/2013/05/backup-and-restore-websql-database-with.html). In that code all you have to do is change the SQL queries and attributes. It exports your database to a file based on [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/).